# Pressing enter key when input is focused 'clicks' first button on form

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a form with inputs and button for cancel.
Pressing enter key when input is focused, clicks first button on form.
Why Click event is fired when focus is on another element?

I tried to remove type="submit" from HTML but the issue still reproduces.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add type="button" on HTML element.
It resolved my issue

Comment: Indeed, I believe submit buttons and forms are a specially bonded kind of implementation wherein most, if not all browsers, go ahead and bind them on an annoyingly helpful but unhelpful way by assuming you want to submit whenever you hit enter when editing forms.

Comment: the default of a button is `type="submit"`